# Showing dates in the chart component

Tags: c#, date, charts

I'm generating a chart using the C# chart class. I can't get dates to show. I've set the X axis label format to "dd/MM/yyyy" and instead of a date on the chart I get the formatting string.

I create my data points like this:

```
DataPoint p = new DataPoint();
p.XValue = item.DayDate.ToOADate();
p.YValues = new Double[] { item.LEVEL };
```

The Y axis displays okay, but the date shows as "dd/MM/yyyy" (the formatting string).

I've set the chart area label style for the date axis like this:

```
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

How do you display the actual date values along the X axis?

Comment: You may also need to make `Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime`

Comment: To make a formatstring work the data need to have the right datatype. So in your case you nned to a)  set the `series.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;` __and b)__ add the data as `DateTime` instead of double: `p.XValue = item.DayDate;`

Comment: ok, got that to work now, setting ChartValueType.DateTime sorted it  thanks guys